# Is there an easy way to edit a variable name to suit a search or edit parameter

Tags: java

so i have created a bunch of buttons 
    `JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
    JButton button3 = new JButton("Button 3");
    JButton button4 = new JButton("Button 4");
    JButton button5 = new JButton("Button 5");
    JButton button6 = new JButton("Button 6");
    JButton button7 = new JButton("Button 7");
    JButton button8 = new JButton("Button 8");
    JButton button9 = new JButton("Button 9");`

and when i go to find them later i want to do one lookup with n. so for *button 1* i want
`n=1
button(n).setIcon();     to change button 1's icon
or
n=5
button(n).setIcon();     to change button 5's icon`

but this doesn't work is there a way to do this easily.
the purpose if this is to allow another method to send an int to this method and the int be used as an identifier to define which button i wish to make the changes too

Comment: arrays are your friend

Comment: Use an `array[]` or an `List<JButton>`

Comment: Yes, it's what's known as an "array".  Or, possibly, a "List" in Java, depending on whether you use the primitive array or a collection object.

Comment: (This is kind of a standard novice question.  Some folks get hung up in this and never progress, others "get it" right away and are fine.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of creating a bunch of `JButton` objects on their own, create an array of size 9.

```
JButton[] buttons = new JButton[9];
for(int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
{
    buttons[i] = new JButton("Button " + (i+1));
}
```

Then you can do

```
n=1;
buttons[n-1].setIcon();
```

Comment: I'd like to +1 you and hooch, but you don't have `{}` around the loop body, and you should *always* use `{}` around the loop body (and `if` or `else` body) even though sometimes you "don't have to".

Comment: @HotLicks If that's all it takes for a +1, you got it :)

Comment: Why using `{}` around a loop body if it has only one line?

Comment: @chryb if the formatting gets messed up and indentation is lost, it could be difficult to tell that something is looping if it's not in braces. Also, it's super annoying when you want to add a printf for debugging and you need to add braces

Comment: @Daniel you could be right, but in my opinion it looks definitely better without braces in a single-line loop.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could add them to an ArrayList...

```
ArrayList<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<JButton>();

buttons.add(button1);
buttons.add(button2);
etc..
```

Then:

```
buttons.get(n-1).setIcon(blah); // Entering 1 will update button 1... 2 will update button 2... etc..
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add all the buttons to an List of buttons. Like in the example:

```
List<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
buttons.add(button1);
...
```

Than you can address the buttons easily with

```
buttons.get(n).setIcon(...);
```

Alternatively you can create an array. An array is better in space using but its more easily to handle with lists.

Hope that helps.